# How do I use ffmpeg to hide a png randomly in one frame of the video?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, png

I like to hide little Easter eggs in all my videos, but it is rather tedious. Is it possible to hide a png in one frame preferably at random locations/orientations within said frame using ffmpeg?

Comment: Only the position/orientation is random, or is the frame number as well?

Comment: Both would be randomized